# Error Blockchain API Class

Tags: php, class, bitcoin, blockchain

Please help to resolve this issue !

```
require('lib/Blockchain.php');
$Blockchain = new \Blockchain\Blockchain("my_api_code");
$Blockchain->Wallet->credentials('id_blockchain', 'password', 'second_pass');
$address = $Blockchain->Wallet->getNewAddress($label=null);
echo $address;
```

Every time i execute the script, i get this error message:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'Blockchain\Create\Create' not found in \lib\Blockchain.php on line 65
```

I am using this class: https://github.com/blockchain/api-v1-client-php

What is the problem please ?

Comment: This Blockchain class looks like it expects to be used with the Composer autoloader, even though its README doesn't say so. Your `require('lib/Blockchain.php')` suggests you are _not_ using an autoloader.

Comment: In particular, its README is suspect because it says to _Copy the lib/ folder into your project_ but it has no `lib/` directory. The docs may be out of date.

Comment: What is the solution in this case ?

Comment: I would start by contacting the developer. There is already an issue open: https://github.com/blockchain/api-v1-client-php/issues/17 and a pull request to fix the documentation. https://github.com/c88lopez/api-v1-client-php/commit/4ff29ab3f3b48daf5f43d6f07513e4b747d00b3e You will probably be able to load the code correctly using the suggested doc correction, but you will first have to familiarize yourself with Composer http://getcomposer.org

Comment: This question appears to be caused by incorrect documentation, which the developer has been made aware of.

Comment: The link not helped me to resolve the problem :/ still same thing !

Comment: Because you must first prepare your project to use Composer. The `require 'vendor/autoload.php';` refers to [the Composer autoloader](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#using-composer). You will then need to add an appropriate require like `"blockchain/blockchain": "*"` in your composer.json. Start looking into how Composer works, and press the Blockchain developer to correct the documentation. [Here is a tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/easy-package-management-with-composer--net-25530)

Comment: I did what you said but i got this error message: `Fatal error: Class 'Blockchain\PushTX\Push' not found in lib\src\Blockchain.php on line 67` :(